# Why Java tells me that a ')' is expected, illegal start of expression?

Tags: java

So I am suppose to write an application that reads values representing a time in hours, minutes, and seconds. Then print the same time in seconds. (For example, 1 hour, 28 minutes, and 42 seconds is equal to 5322 seconds.) I use JCreator and when I try to compile, it's telling me I have 2 errors on line 21 which is
System.out.println ("Your answer equals =" +time "seconds");
and the errors it's telling me is that ')' is expected and illegal start of expression.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class StackOverflow.swag // for teh lulz
    {
        public static void main (String [] args);
        {
            double time, hours, minutes, seconds;
            seconds = 0.0;
            minutes = minutes*3600;
            hours = hours*216000;
            time = seconds+minutes+hours;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

            System.out.println ("Enter number of hours");
            hours = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println ("Enter number of minutes");
            minutes = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println ("Enter number of seconds");
            seconds = scan.nextDouble();


            System.out.println ("Your answer equals =" +time+ "seconds");


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a `+` between `time` and `"seconds"`.  Change

```
System.out.println ("Your answer equals =" +time "seconds");
```

to

```
System.out.println ("Your answer equals =" + time + "seconds");
```

Also, there is a semicolon after your `main` method signature that is incorrect syntax.  Change

```
public static void main (String [] args);
```

to

```
public static void main (String [] args)
```

Comment: When I do that, it tells me "missing method body, or declare abstract" on line 4

Comment: @Sam That semicolon should not be there; see my updated answer.

Comment: Ya I did that, but then I realized I also set the values of the variables too early, so I made it work now.